# Angular Resource not sending request to API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, get, ngresource

I am writing a basic CRUD Angular app of sorts and have been using `$resource` throughout. The issue is that when I am trying to issue a get request to an API endpoint I am getting an error in resource:

```
[Log] Object (job-detail.js, line 30)
config: Object
headers: Object
method: "GET"
transformRequest: Array[1]
transformResponse: Array[1]
url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/estimators/1"
__proto__: Object
data: null
headers: function (name) {
  get arguments: function () {
  get caller: function () {
  length: 1
  name: ""
  prototype: Object
  set arguments: function () {
  set caller: function () {
  __proto__: function () {
  status: 0
  statusText: ""
__proto__: Object
```

I have no idea what is going wrong because I have tested that URL and it works fine. Also, I have used `$resource` in the exact same fashion, just on a different endpoint and it is working fine. Lastly, `$resource` isn't even sending the request, on my API it's not logging any requests to the endpoint. I am at a loss, here is the relevant code:

```
angular.module('lincorFeApp.controllers')
.controller('JobDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Estimator', '$location', 
  function($scope, $routeParams, Estimator, $location) {

      getEstimator();

      function getEstimator() {
          $scope.estimator = Estimator.get({ pk : $scope.job.estimator }, function() {
              console.log($scope.estimator.name);
          }, function(response) {
              console.log(response);
          });
      }
  }
```

]);

and in `services.js`:

```
myApp.factory('Estimator', function($resource) {
    return $resource('http://127.0.0.1:8000/estimators/:pk', { pk : '@pk' }, {
        update : { method: 'PUT' },
        delete : { method: 'DELETE' }
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the error? Why do you have a getEstimator() function that's not defined as $scope.getEstimator()?

Comment: What is the proper way to declare a function in an Angular controller? And what specifically are you looking for in regards to the error? I already posted it above. That is the response that I printed out to the console.

Comment: I guess you mentioned "$resource isn't even sending the request" so I don't get what is producing that error (doesn't seem like an error, just a dump of call - I don't see the error) above? Typically you would have $scope.getEstimator() = function() { ....} and then a call to it (from the controller) $scope.getEstimator() or in the template/html getEstimator()

Comment: In the controller code-snippet where I call `Estimator.get()` I have a function to handle the error, which is `response` being printed to the console. I'm not sure how to explain it but I don't think `$resource` is actually sending the request because the API doesn't log any requests to that API endpoint. Maybe a better word for it is dump or whatever.

Comment: Hard to say what the error is. You probably did these, but first I would make sure  http://127.0.0.1:8000/estimators/1  returns something in a browser. Then I see you don't have 'get' in the $resource but I believe that's the default. You have a status of 0 which could mean anything including no connection. Otherwise not sure.

Comment: Ok thanks, Yeah I am positive it is the right URL because when I copy and paste and then use `curl` in terminal it works correctly, so I have no idea what the issue could be....